# Silverlight custom Font not working at runtime

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, fonts

I have a Silverlight 4 Application that I run using Visual Studio 2012 Web Express.  I added a CustomFont.zip in the Fonts folder of my project.  the file is marked as "Resource".

When I use the font, in a TextBlock for example, I can see it in the Visual Studio XAML designer.  But when I run the application it uses de default standard font.

Here's an example of my TextBlock

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="/Fonts/CustomFont.zip#MyFontName" >Hello World</TextBlock>
```

I have tried with embedded Zip like the example above.  I also tried the font directly (without zip).  Tried with TTF and OTF Font.  Always same result I can see it at design time but not at runtime.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have this working by now but I had the same problem. I got it to work by formatting my FontFamily string like below and you definitely don't want the file to be in a zip file.  I have my font in a project folder I created called "Fonts".

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="./Fonts/MyFontName.ttf#MyFontName" >Hello World</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it working like you said, but don't know what I changed to make it work.  I am still using a zip file.  It just started working all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same problem and I solved like below. I had to go through a lot of forums including this but none works. But some forum asked me to forcibly load font before I come to point of my interest.

In my TextBlockStyles.xaml resource dictionary I created a styke

```
<Style x:Key="RadWindowTitleTextStyle"
         TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="#FFB9D449" />
      <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="18.667" />
      <Setter Property="FontFamily"
            Value="/sampleawebsite.application;component/Assets/Fonts/UBSHead.ttf#UBSHeadline" />
      </Style>
```

In my MainPage, I just gave below to load my font

```
<TextBlock Text="Do not display Font load purpose only"
                   Width="1"
                   Height="1"
                   Style="{StaticResource RadWindowTitleTextStyle}"
                   Foreground="Transparent" />
```

Below is my point of interest in one of my ChildWindow popup styles resource dictionary called RadWindowStyles.xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"
           Style="{StaticResource RadWindowTitleTextStyle}" />
```