# Custom font does not display during runtime in silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, fonts

I can not seem to get a custom font to show during runtime in ISS Express nor runtime in my azure website. The font shows during design time fine.

There is a post here on stack that never recieved a proper answer as well. Just posting here as reference
[Silverlight custom Font not working at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020581/silverlight-custom-font-not-working-at-runtime)

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="36"
                   Foreground="#FFD32E2E"
                   FontFamily="/theApp;component/Marmallata(Jam)_demo.ttf#Marmellata (Jam)_demo">the App</TextBlock>

<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="36"
                   Foreground="#FFD32E2E"
                   FontFamily="/Marmallata(Jam)_demo.ttf#Marmellata (Jam)_demo">the App</TextBlock>

<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="36"
                   Foreground="#FFD32E2E"
                   FontFamily="./Marmallata(Jam)_demo.ttf#Marmellata (Jam)_demo">the App</TextBlock>
```

My file is in the root of my silverlight application with build action set to resource and copy always.

I thought maybe it wasn't properly getting copied to the website root so I ftp-ed the file to wwwroot, bin, and ClientBin with still no luck.

Comment: Try using Fiddler to track the browser requests. Do you see any failed requests for the font file?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what to look for. This is new to me. I do see an error symbol and a line stating "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
the file you have requested has been changed, moved, or deleted" I don't have an icon named favicon in my server nor even know where that came from. I did not see anything relating to a .ttf file though...

Comment: Sorry, I think I misled you here. Since you mentioned copying the file to wwwroot etc. I assumed that the font file was supposed to be downloaded separately by the Silverlight runtime. Whereas in fact the font file is embedded in the .xap. I looked into this a little further and it seems that Silverlight has no support for loading font files externally, only files embedded in the .xap. Glad you got it working anyway. Oh, and the favicon.ico thingy has nothing to do with Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved the issue using the previously provided link:
*[Silverlight custom Font not working at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020581/silverlight-custom-font-not-working-at-runtime)*

In my frantic effort of trial and error I decided to try and add the actual .zip file the font came in to my project as is and reference that instead of the actual .ttf file and it seems to be working now.

For those of you who might run into this issue this is my exact line of code.

```
FontFamily="./fontscafe_marmellata-jam-demo.zip#Marmellata (Jam)_demo"
```